# Trying to do a docker build which fails at chromadb installation

Tags: python-3.x, docker, langchain, duckdb, chromadb

I am trying to build a docker image for my python flask project.

Seems like there is some issue with the below packages on which Chromadb build is dependent

1. duckdb,
2. hnswlib

Below are the contents of the docker file.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster
ENV HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt



RUN export HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1

RUN pip install chromadb

EXPOSE 5000

CMD python ./app.py
```

The docker build fails at "RUN pip install chromadb" with the below error pointing out "Could not build wheels for duckdb, hnswlib"-

```
Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
#0 9.427   │ exit code: 1
#0 9.427   ╰─> [55 lines of output]
#0 9.427       running bdist_wheel
#0 9.427       running build
#0 9.427       running build_ext
#0 9.427       creating tmp
#0 9.427       gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c /tmp/tmpohs_vaib.cpp -o tmp/tmpohs_vaib.o -std=c++14
#0 9.427       gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c /tmp/tmp1os2pqqf.cpp -o tmp/tmp1os2pqqf.o -std=c++11
#0 9.427       Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 9.427         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
#0 9.427           main()
#0 9.427         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
#0 9.427           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
#0 9.427         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
#0 9.427           return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
#0 9.427           return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
#0 9.427           self.run_setup()
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
#0 9.427           exec(code, locals())
#0 9.427         File "<string>", line 116, in <module>
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
#0 9.427           return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
#0 9.427           return run_commands(dist)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
#0 9.427           dist.run_commands()
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
#0 9.427           self.run_command(cmd)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
#0 9.427           super().run_command(command)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
#0 9.427           cmd_obj.run()
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
#0 9.427           self.run_command("build")
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
#0 9.427           self.distribution.run_command(command)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
#0 9.427           super().run_command(command)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
#0 9.427           cmd_obj.run()
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
#0 9.427           self.run_command(cmd_name)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
#0 9.427           self.distribution.run_command(command)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
#0 9.427           super().run_command(command)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
#0 9.427           cmd_obj.run()
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
#0 9.427           _build_ext.run(self)
#0 9.427         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-o2mbvvt6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run
#0 9.427           self.build_extensions()
#0 9.427         File "<string>", line 103, in build_extensions
#0 9.427         File "<string>", line 70, in cpp_flag
#0 9.427       RuntimeError: Unsupported compiler -- at least C++11 support is needed!
#0 9.427       [end of output]
#0 9.427   
#0 9.427   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 9.427   ERROR: Failed building wheel for hnswlib
#0 9.428 Failed to build duckdb hnswlib
#0 9.428 ERROR: Could not build wheels for duckdb, hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
------
Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  13 |     RUN export HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1
  14 |     
  15 | >>> RUN pip install chromadb
  16 |     
  17 |     EXPOSE 5000
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install chromadb" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace - RuntimeError: Unsupported compiler -- at least C++11 support is needed!
#0 9.427       [end of output]

This was solved by installing C++ Complier

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding an apt-get line to the top of my Dockerfile as discussed here in the hnswlib issues: https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/642

```
# Needed to build hnswlib during pip install. 
# See here https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/642
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y --fix-missing build-essential
```

Presumably the issue is that the python-slim base image I was using did not (unlike my laptop) have the build tools needed for pip to build during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing hnswlib from source,
as mentioned here:
https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib/issues/442#issuecomment-1529328244